# Best way to match all patterns in a string?

Tags: c#, regex, string

What would be the optimal way to match that all of a set of patterns exist within a given string. For example, assume I have a collection of many thousand strings of medium length (about 30-50 characters each). The user needs to be able to specify a set of patterns (not even patterns just a series of characters really) that each string will be evaluated for, the string must contain ALL the patterns specified.

so assume the user wants to evaluate for the following patterns:

```
123
xyz
abc
```

a string like:

```
john_smith_123456_abcdef_9999_tuv
```

would be false because it only contains 2 of the 3, while a string like:

```
jane_doe_abcdef_123_9999_tuvwxyz
```

would be true as it contains all 3

So first of all, regex or string.Contains()? Or is there a tradeof point where one performs better than the other? And second, assuming that regex is the way to go, what would be the optimal type of regex expression to use for this scenario?

thanks a lot!

Comment: You might want to consider http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is specific strings inside the big string, right?  If so, regex wouldn't do you much good here.  Sure, you could do some lookahead thing, but you haven't really gained anything -- either readabilitywise, or performancewise.  Regular expressions are for finding *patterns* in text, not so much for *substrings*.

Just iterate through the list, array, whatever...and look for each substring using `Contains`.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will work:

```
^(?=.*123)(?=.*xyz)(?=.*abc).*$
```

This uses [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure that the three substrings you want to find are contained somewhere in the string, and then uses `.*` to consume the entire string if all of the substrings were found.

Comment: Good. Used in combination with Regex.Escape, it would be possible to programmatically generate a regex against a list of input strings.

Comment: thanks for the expression...but I'm inclined to believe that given that I will always be searching for pure substrings moreso than expressions that string.Contains() will outperform even the cleverest of regexs, would you agree or do you think the lookaheads will make enough of a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are pretty much always the slower option for simple matching. You should use `String.Contains()` unless you actually need regular expression functionality. If the user will only be allowed to enter actual strings to test against, you don't need regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression seems like overkill for such a simple task.  You're not really looking for a *pattern* so much as a substring, in which case `String.Contains()` is perfectly suited for the job (assuming you have no "hidden" requirements that you haven't told us about).

Answer (score 0):

There's no rule of thumb for deciding when a regex based solution will be too slow.  In fact, there's no reason to expect regexes to be slower than any other technology.  Like any other tool, if you're reasonably competent at using it and it seems to offer the simplest approach, go ahead and try it.  When you've got enough code written for tests to be meaningful, benchmark it.

Besides, if the patterns are so simple that you can use `Contains()`, there's also very little chance of messing up the regex and creating a <strike>resonance cascade</strike> catastrophic backtracking scenario.  Remember: regexes don't fry CPU's, regex authors do. :D

I tend to agree with you about the multiple-lookahead approach as proposed by [FJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10096932/20938); it's probably too slow for this job.  It's effectively the same as calling `Contains()` multiple times, but with additional overhead due to backtracking.  It's worth testing anyway, but I'd try this approach first:

```
^(?>(?:123()|xyz()|abc()|.)+$\1\2\3)
```

Where the lookahead approach has to scan potentially the whole string for each search term, this regex scans it exactly once, and it never backtracks.  Each time it gets a hit on a search term, the capturing group immediately following that term is said to have *participated in the match*, even though it captures nothing.  When the end of the string is reached, each backreference "matches nothing" again if the group participated in the match; otherwise it reports failure and the overall match fails.